# Remove duplicate entries from mysql without applying unique key

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a table with people, which contains duplicate people since the very beginning. Sadly, sometimes data is hooked to one or the other of the duplicates, so i'd rather keep them, because those records are not part of the issue, removing those would cause more issues.

Someone updated the user-creation code 2 days ago, which ended up in spawning massive amount of duplicates(literally thousands). I need to remove all the duplicates from the last 2 days. I cannot use the 'unique key approach' because the older duplicates have data attached to them(bookings etc). 
Does anyone have an idea how to resolve an issue like this? I explicitly want to remove the duplicates from the last 2 days only, leaving 1 copy of each person in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `people_copy` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `lastname` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `birthplace` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `birth_country` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `blocked_from` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=42095 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Checking if the records are duplicate can be concluded by using the columns:
firstname, lastname, birthdate, birthplace, birth_country

Comment: What does the table look like? Do you have a creation date? please so some examples.

Comment: It is time to fix your data.  Take this as an opportunity to reconstruct the table and fix the foreign key relationships.

Comment: Does the table include a column indicating when the record was created?  Do you have a backup of the table from before the problem occurred?  Do you also need to adjust any other tables which may have FK references to these records?  It sounds like this partial acceptance of duplicates over time is finally resulting in a bigger problem.  I suspect cleaning the data wouldn't "cause more issues" quite so much as *solve* them, difficult though it may be.

Comment: @bit, Sorry, indeed forgot to put in the table. It is updated now.

Comment: @gordon, there is sadly no time to spend on fixing the rest of the data. It is for work and time is limited.

Comment: @David. 1. Yes, created_at and updated_at. 2. Yes. 3. There are no foreign keys defined in this table as it is constructed by newbs. 4. Im pretty sure that it would cause more issues. Some duplicates have 1 version linked to 1 part of data, the second version linked to another part of data. It is a mess, but i do not have time to clean all the inconsistencies because work does not allow me to.

Answer (score 0):

In this case what you can do is create another table with same schema and make a combined unique column in this table from there columns: `firstname, lastname, birthdate, birthplace, birth_country`.

Now you can write data from the first table to the new table using a stored procedure or custom program. After that delete the 2 days data from the old table and store the data from new table to old table.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE MAIN_TABLE
FROM people_copy as CHILD, people_copy as MAIN_TABLE
WHERE
          (CHILD.company_id   = MAIN_TABLE.company_id OR CHILD.company_id IS NULL AND MAIN_TABLE.company_id IS NULL)
      AND (CHILD.firstname = MAIN_TABLE.firstname OR CHILD.firstname IS NULL AND MAIN_TABLE.firstname IS NULL)
      AND (CHILD.lastname = MAIN_TABLE.lastname OR CHILD.lastname IS NULL AND MAIN_TABLE.lastname IS NULL)
      AND CHILD.ID < MAIN_TABLE.ID AND CHILD.created_at > DATE_ADD(SYSDATE(),INTERVAL -2 DAY);
```

Here you can self join that table and compare how many columns you want to compare.
This will help you.
[**`You can check SQL Fiddle demo`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24d2fd/1)